# The root path .../dir/ is not readable - DDEV on WSL2

Tags: php, ubuntu, ddev

Installed DDEV on my Windows machine (Ubuntu on WSL2), cloned CMS (ExpressionEngine) files from github, created a DDEV project (php), downloaded contents of my *img/* folder from production server... and got this error:

`LogicException Caught`
`The root path /home/shbchk/project/httpdocs/img/films/ is not readable.`

What should I do here?

`chmod -R 777 img/` didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error coming from DDEV, or the path would be /var/www/html/project..., assuming that you put your project in /home/shbchk/project.

(If your project is named "project" and is in /home/shbchk/project, then inside the web container it will be mounted at /var/www/html, and the files will be at /var/www/html/httpdocs/img; Inside the container, in the world the webserver inhabits, there won't be any references to /home/shbchk.)

I'm not sure *when* or how you got this error, but if it was when you were copying files, try using sudo to copy the files, and then chown the files to your user. For example, if your user is `shbchk` then `sudo chown -R shbchk /home/shbchk/project` to change the ownership on all the files.

Comment: Thank you, rfay (himself, wow!) :) 

Didn't notice your answer before I answered my own question, but I came to this answer myself using PHP pwd variable :)

BTW, thank you very much for DDEV, it's really great!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.
Path in a DDEV container is not the actual WSL2-Ubuntu path.
This is it:

```
/var/www/html/httpdocs
```